# MySQL: FROM multiple tables to Join

Tags: mysql

I am having a bit of a hard time representing a query. The statement that I want to convert to a SQL statement is:

```
select count(*)
from assigned, tasks
where 
assigned.id_task = 1
or 
(assigned.id_project=tasks.id_project and tasks.id=1)
```

What I succeeded to come up so far is:

```
select count(*) 
from assigned a 
left join projects p
  on p.id=a.id_project
left join tasks t
  on t.id_project=p.id
where (a.id_task=1 or t.id=1)
```

However, the second is not returning the correct result. What am I missing?

Comment: What is your expected result? How is the second query result wrong? Where does this projects table come from (it's not in the first select)? How are your tables defined?

Comment: The first statement already is a SQL statement.  In what way do you want to "*convert it*"?

Comment: @eggyal is it fine? Compared to selecting directly from tables, aren't joins faster?

Comment: @OlafDietsche First query returns 1, the second 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised, that the second query returns a different result, because it uses an additional table and different join criteria. Although the second select should deliver at least as many rows as the first, because the first uses an inner join and the second a left join.

The first query uses a join as well. It is just expressed implicitly.

Comment: Right. I answered the question with the query that returns the same results as the first. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured out where the problem was. The correct `join` query is:

```
select count(*) 
from assigned a 
left join tasks t
  on t.id_project=a.id_project
where (a.id_task=1 or t.id=1)
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution.